# Deleting every 2nd and 3rd row using VBA

Tags: excel, dataset, vba

I am looking for insight on quickly removing two-thirds of a medium sized dataset. Currently, I am importing the space-delimited data into Excel from a text file, and I am using a loop to delete the data row by row. The loop starts on the bottom most row of the data and deletes rows going up. The data is chronologically ordered, and I can't simply chop off the first or last two thirds of the data. Essentially what is happening is the data is being over sampled and too many data points exists too close to one another. It is a painstakingly slow process, and I am just looking for another method.

```
Sub Delete()

Dim n As Long

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("A:A"))

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Do While n > 5

n = n - 1
Rows(n).Delete
n = n - 1
Rows(n).Delete
n = n - 1

Loop

   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Also, I looked into multi-selecting all of the rows of interest in the loop and performing the delete with one line of code after all of the rows were selected, but couldn't figure out a way of doing this. I would assume this would likely increase the overall computation time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for loop that allows the stepping by a certain number:

> `For i = 8 To n Step 3`

Use Union to create a disjointed range stored in a range variable.

> `Set rng = Union(rng, .Range(.Cells(i + 1, 1), .Cells(i + 2, 1)))`

Then delete all at once.

> `rng.EntireRow.Delete`

Another good habit to encourage is the use of **ALWAYS** declaring the parent of any range objects.  As your code gets more and more complicated, not declaring the parents can lead to problems.

By using the `With` block.

> `With Worksheets("Sheet1")`

we can precede all the range objects with `.` to denote the link to that parent.

> `Set rng = .Range("A6:A7")`

```
Sub Delete()

Dim n As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change to your sheet
    n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(.Range("A:A"))

    Set rng = .Range("A6:A7")

    For i = 8 To n Step 3
        Set rng = Union(rng, .Range(.Cells(i + 1, 1), .Cells(i + 2, 1)))
    Next i
End With

rng.EntireRow.Delete

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic    


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this tomorrow. Do you expect to see a large decrease in computation time using this method?

Comment: @Jesse yes as it only does the delete once.

Comment: I compared your method to the original one using a small dataset, and it is roughly 225% faster. Using the same dataset, the loops took 519s and 231s to execute. Both sets of code are in an .xlsm that have a lot of other sheets, modules, etc. I then took my original code and inserted it into an empty .xlsm and timed it again, and it took 71s to execute. I assume your method would take ~30s in an empty .xlsm. So my next question: Are there any other properties that I can disable during the loop to speed things up?

Comment: @Jesse Yes, disable all events and screen updating.  Make sure to re-enable them before leaving the macro.  Please remember to mark an answer as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Could you be more specific on disabling all events? I have tried disabling screen updates as well asApplication.Calculation = xlCalculationManual. My code is just much slower in the larger spreadsheet and I can't seem to get it to execute as quickly as it does in an empty spreadsheet.

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = False` and make sure it is set back to True before ending the sub.  But this will only effect the code if you have events.  Events are code in that fire when things happen; like Worksheet_Change or Worksheet_calculate @Jesse

Answer (score 0):

You could use arrays and write out one-third of the rows into a new array. Then print out to the screen after clearing the original.

You would lose formulas if any are there. If you had just a basic dataset, this might suit you. It should be fast

```
Sub MyDelete()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion  'perhaps define better
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 1)  ' I assume row 1 is header row.

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = r.Value

    Dim newArr() As Variant
    ReDim newArr(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To UBound(arr, 2))
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, newCounter As Long
    i = 1
    newCounter = 1

    Do
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            newArr(newCounter, j) = arr(i, j)
        Next j

        newCounter = newCounter + 1
        i = i + 3
    Loop While i <= UBound(arr)

    r.ClearContents
    Sheet1.Range("A2").Resize(newCounter - 1, UBound(arr, 2)).Value = newArr

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```